# How to grep a specific integer

Tags: grep

I have a list of number in a file with format: {integer}\n . So a possible list is:

```
3
12
53
23
18
32
1
4
```

i want to use grep to get the count of a specific number, but **grep -c "1" file** results 3 because it takes into account except the 1, the 12, 18 also. How can i correct this?

Although all the answers until now are logical, and i thought of them and tested before, actually nothing works:

```
username@domain2:~/code/***/project/random/r2$ cat out.txt
2
16
11
1
13
2
1
16
16
9
username@domain2:~/code/***/project/random/r2$ grep -Pc "^1$" out.txt
0
username@domain2:~/code/***/project/random/r2$ grep -Pc ^1$ out.txt
0
username@domain2:~/code/***/project/random/r2$ grep -c ^1$ out.txt
0
username@domain2:~/code/***/project/random/r2$ grep -c "^1$" out.txt
0
username@domain2:~/code/***/project/random/r2$ grep -xc "^1$" out.txt
0
username@domain2:~/code/***/project/random/r2$ grep -xc "1" out.txt
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a some other ways you can do this besides grep

```
$ cat file
3 1 2 100
12 x x x
53
23
18
32
1
4

$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="1") c++}END{print c}' file
2

$ ruby -0777 -ne 'puts $_.scan(/\b1\b/).size' file
2

$ grep -o '\b1\b' file | wc -l
2

$ tr " " "\n" < file | grep -c "\b1\b"
2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-x` flag:

```
grep -xc 1 file
```

This is what it means:

```
-x, --line-regexp
     Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
```

Comment: It does not work, i have already test this and every time yields 0, but i see instances of the numbers in the file! I test both: grep -xc 1 file and grep -xc "1" file.

Comment: A caveat is that multiple instances of "1" in the current won't be matched.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex...

```
\D1\D
```

...or `^1$` with multiline mode on.

[Tested with RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and they [both](http://regexr.com?2t6qn) [work](http://regexr.com?2t6qk).

Answer (score 1):

Use e.g. `^123$` to match "Beginning of line, 123, End of line"

Comment: That returns the objects found instead of the number of occurrences. A more accurate suggestion would be, for instance, if you want to count how many 3's are in the document: `grep ^3$ nums_list.txt | wc -l`

Comment: Note that I only answered with a change to his regex, not a complete grep commandline. grep -c "^123$" will count occurences of 123.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -wc '23' filename.txt
```

It will count the number of exact matches of digit 23.